# Visual Studio allows branch change with Azure Dev Ops Git mode

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I was working in a prior project where, if I tried to change branches locally without committing my changes first, would error and insist I do that first. However, the current project I'm working in lets my change branches without committing changes, which is more dangerous of course (checking code into the wrong branch).

I'm trying to figure out if this is a policy in Azure Dev Ops that was set in my one project, that isn't in this new one. I didn't see a Visual Studio (2017) answer to this, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Both behaviors are standard, correct Git behaviors that have nothing to do with either Visual Studio *or* Azure DevOps.

If you have changes to a file and the file isn't different between branches, you can freely switch branches.

If you have changes to a file and the file **is** different, it complains that you have to either undo the changes, stash them, or commit them.

Comment: Interesting. I know there are changes to the file, for example from the master branch to a feature branch I'm doing. I change a particular file, and then switch to the master branch, it allows me to do this when I'd expect it to stop me. In the Azure Dev Ops repo I'm set as a project admin, could this be why?

Comment: Like I said, this is Git behavior. It has nothing to do with anything other than Git.